# C#: IBM MQ 'unlock' message when using Read() method

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

My code:

```
        //Initialize MQMessage
        MQMessage message = new MQMessage();

        //Initialize WebMQConnection
        WebSphereMQConnection mqRequestConnection = new WebSphereMQConnection(initQMName, initQChannel, initQConnection, initQName, string.Empty, string.Empty);
        mqRequestConnection.Open();
        mqRequestConnection.Read(message);


        //Get the contents as a string
        string body = message.ReadString(message.MessageLength);
        return body;
```

This code is part of a console application and works as expected for browsing the queue sequentially and reading each message. It parses the string content from a flat file.

However, it seems that the Read() method also locks the message until the program is closed. Even if I run the program in a loop to sequentially read all messages, it doesn't seem to 'release' the messages until the program is closed entirely.

I've tried Gets and Puts, Dispose, Backout, etc. and nothing seems to work besides halting the execution of the entire console app.

Comment: `WebSphereMQConnection` does not look like something provided by IBM.  Can you post what this is doing?  Is it opening the queue under syncpoint?  If so you need to add commit for MQ to "release" the messages.

Comment: @JoshMc It's a constructor for the class that eventually creates a Queue manager upon calling Open() that handles the Syncpoint operations. It's legacy code that I don't have much control over. I've tried adding a commit but it doesn't seem to do anything. I'm beginning to think the problem may be with the core code that I've been given.

Comment: Perhaps there is a method that performs a commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Initialize WebMQConnection
WebSphereMQConnection mqRequestConnection = new WebSphereMQConnection(initQMName, initQChannel, initQConnection, initQName, string.Empty, string.Empty);
mqRequestConnection.Open();
mqRequestConnection.Read(message);
```

What in the world is that?  It is certainly not IBM MQ class and methods.  So, it is a home-grown class.

So, the Read() method actually performs a 'browse'.  Poorly named method.  I bet that in your Read() method, it is using the MQGMO_LOCK option on the MQGET.

Why don't you get rid of the WebSphereMQConnection class and just write pure IBM MQ .NET code?

Here is a MQ CS .NET sample program to browse a queue without any message locking:

```
using System;
using IBM.WMQ;

/// <summary> Program Name
/// MQTest62B
///
/// Description
/// This C# class will connect to a remote queue manager
/// and get (browse) a message from a queue using a managed .NET environment.
///
/// Sample Command Line Parameters
/// -h 127.0.0.1 -p 1415 -c TEST.CHL -m MQWT1 -q TEST.Q1
/// </summary>
/// <author>  Roger Lacroix, Capitalware Inc.
/// </author>
namespace MQTest62
{
    public class MQTest62B
    {
        private System.Collections.Hashtable inParms = null;
        private System.String qManager;
        private System.String outputQName;
        private System.String userID = "tester";
        private System.String password = "barney";

        /*
        * The constructor
        */
        public MQTest62B()
            : base()
        {
        }

        /// <summary> Make sure the required parameters are present.</summary>
        /// <returns> true/false
        /// </returns>
        private bool allParamsPresent()
        {
            bool b = inParms.ContainsKey("-h") && inParms.ContainsKey("-p") &&
                     inParms.ContainsKey("-c") && inParms.ContainsKey("-m") &&
                     inParms.ContainsKey("-q");
            if (b)
            {
                try
                {
                    System.Int32.Parse((System.String)inParms["-p"]);
                }
                catch (System.FormatException e)
                {
                    b = false;
                }
            }

            return b;
        }

        /// <summary> Extract the command-line parameters and initialize the MQ variables.</summary>
        /// <param name="args">
        /// </param>
        /// <throws>  IllegalArgumentException </throws>
        private void init(System.String[] args)
        {
            inParms = System.Collections.Hashtable.Synchronized(new System.Collections.Hashtable(14));
            if (args.Length > 0 && (args.Length % 2) == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i += 2)
                {
                    inParms[args[i]] = args[i + 1];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentException();
            }

            if (allParamsPresent())
            {
                qManager = ((System.String)inParms["-m"]);
                outputQName = ((System.String)inParms["-q"]);
                // Set up MQ environment
                MQEnvironment.Hostname = ((System.String)inParms["-h"]);
                MQEnvironment.Channel = ((System.String)inParms["-c"]);
                try
                {
                    MQEnvironment.Port = System.Int32.Parse((System.String)inParms["-p"]);
                }
                catch (System.FormatException e)
                {
                    MQEnvironment.Port = 1414;
                }

                if (userID != null)
                    MQEnvironment.UserId = userID;

                if (password != null)
                    MQEnvironment.Password = password;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentException();
            }
        }

        /// <summary> Connect, open queue, read (browse) a message, close queue and disconnect. </summary>
        ///
        private void testReceive()
        {
            MQQueueManager qMgr = null;
            MQQueue inQ = null;
            int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_BROWSE + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;

            try
            {
                qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager);
                System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQTest62B successfully connected to " + qManager);

                inQ = qMgr.AccessQueue(outputQName, openOptions, null, null, null); // no alternate user id
                System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQTest62B successfully opened " + outputQName);

                testLoop(inQ);

            }
            catch (MQException mqex)
            {
                System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQTest62B cc=" + mqex.CompletionCode + " : rc=" + mqex.ReasonCode);
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException ioex)
            {
                System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQTest62B ioex=" + ioex);
            }
            finally
            {
               try
               {
                   if (inQ != null)
                       inQ.Close();
                   System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQTest62B closed: " + outputQName);
               }
               catch (MQException mqex)
               {
                   System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQTest62B cc=" + mqex.CompletionCode + " : rc=" + mqex.ReasonCode);
               }

               try
               {
                   if (qMgr != null)
                       qMgr.Disconnect();
                   System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQTest62B disconnected from " + qManager);
               }
               catch (MQException mqex)
               {
                   System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQTest62B cc=" + mqex.CompletionCode + " : rc=" + mqex.ReasonCode);
               }
            }
        }

        private void testLoop(MQQueue inQ)
        {
            bool flag = true;
            MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
            MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
            gmo.Options |= MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT | MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
            gmo.WaitInterval = 500;  // 1/2 second wait time   or MQC.MQEI_UNLIMITED

            while (flag)
            {
                try
                {
                    msg = new MQMessage();
                    inQ.Get(msg, gmo);
                    System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Message Data: " + msg.ReadString(msg.MessageLength));
                }
                catch (MQException mqex)
                {
                    System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQTest62B CC=" + mqex.CompletionCode + " : RC=" + mqex.ReasonCode);
                    if (mqex.Reason == MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE)
                    {
                        // no meesage - life is good - loop again
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        flag = false;  // severe error - time to exit
                    }
                }
                catch (System.IO.IOException ioex)
                {
                    System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQTest62B ioex=" + ioex);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary> main line</summary>
        /// <param name="args">
        /// </param>
        //        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(System.String[] args)
        {
            MQTest62B write = new MQTest62B();

            try
            {
                write.init(args);
                write.testReceive();
            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException e)
            {
                System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Usage: MQTest62B -h host -p port -c channel -m QueueManagerName -q QueueName");
                System.Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            catch (MQException e)
            {
                System.Console.Out.WriteLine(e);
                System.Environment.Exit(1);
            }

            System.Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```